# Facebook Crawler Returns 404 for internal pages of react App

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React Application. It has a blog section as well. It's still under development. I was testing og:image tags and Facebook share preview using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/.

Please note I am getting my blog post and og image from an API response.

However, I noticed the Facebook tool return error code 404 for all internal pages like [www.xyz.com/blog/my-first-post](http://www.xyz.com/blog/my-first-post). Secondly, it does not detect the og image tag I am injecting using react-helmet.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not using any server side rendering. If your website is SEO extensive then you basically need to setup a Node express render your website on the server side. Otherwise you can use Nextjs as it comes with SSR out of the box.